# Installing SANE backends via Mac OS X terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, twain, sane

Where can I find sane-backends after performing these commands in the terminal:

$ cd Downloads

$ sudo installer -pkg sane-backends.pkg -target /

note: 
- sane-backends.pkg is located inside Downloads folder.
- I downloaded sane-backends.pkg together with 4 other files here http://www.ellert.se/twain-sane/

I want to know where sane-backends is located to add a driver to the list of SANE drivers which is shown when you open SANE from System Preferences.